# How to solve the AttributeError: 'Snake' object has no attribute 'segments'?

Tags: python, oop

I was trying to write the snake game, but the attribute error kept showing up.

AttributeError: 'Snake' object has no attribute 'segments'

This is the main.py file

```
from snake import Snake
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import time

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.title('SNAKE GAME')
screen.tracer(0)  # turn off the tracer

snake = Snake()

game_is_on = True
while game_is_on:
    screen.update()  #  only update when all segs are in right positions
    time.sleep(0.1)
    snake.move()

screen.exitonclick()
```

This is the snake.py file

```
import time

STARTING_POSITIOBS = [(0, 0), (-20, 0), (-40, 0)]
MOVE_DISTANCE = 20

class Snake:
    def __init__(self):
        segments = []
        self.create_snake()
        self.move()

    def create_snake(self):
        for position in STARTING_POSITIOBS:
            new_segment = Turtle("square")
            new_segment.color('white')
            new_segment.penup()
            new_segment.goto(position)
            self.segments.append(new_segment)

    def move(self):
        for seg_num in range(len(self.segments) - 1, 0, -1):  # start=2, stop=0, step=-1
            new_x = self.segments[seg_num - 1].xcor()
            new_y = self.segments[seg_num - 1].ycor()  # get the position of second last seg
            self.segments[seg_num].goto(new_x, new_y)  # reverse order, let the last seg move to the second last seg position
        self.segments[0].forward(MOVE_DISTANCE)
```

Comment: In the `__init__` method of `Snake`, you should call it `self.segments` not just `segments`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import time

STARTING_POSITIOBS = [(0, 0), (-20, 0), (-40, 0)]
MOVE_DISTANCE = 20

class Snake:
    def __init__(self):
        self.segments = []
        # segments = []
        self.create_snake()
        self.move()

    def create_snake(self):
        for position in STARTING_POSITIOBS:
            new_segment = Turtle("square")
            new_segment.color('white')
            new_segment.penup()
            new_segment.goto(position)
            self.segments.append(new_segment)

    def move(self):
        for seg_num in range(len(self.segments) - 1, 0, -1):  # start=2, stop=0, step=-1
            new_x = self.segments[seg_num - 1].xcor()
            new_y = self.segments[seg_num - 1].ycor()  # get the position of second last seg
            self.segments[seg_num].goto(new_x, new_y)  # reverse order, let the last seg move to the second last seg position
        self.segments[0].forward(MOVE_DISTANCE)
```

`segments` wasn't an attribute before.